# Multiple WAN loadbalancing?

Tags: cisco, load-balancing, wide-area-network, adsl

What's the best way to load balance multiple DSL LAN connections in a small office (circa 30 people). If there is a Cisco product that can do this, please recommend, as it will help comply with a broader support contract.

Answer (score 1):

pfSense is the Best and IDEAL solution, which is FREE as well.
you would come up with many many solutions, like untangle, ubuntu based Zentyal, monowall etc, but there is nothing as compared to Free and open source solution as PfSense.
i am myself using it my company of more than 500 employees with multiple site offices, all connected through PfSense routers.
read more about how easy load balancing is done in PfSense:
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi_WAN_/_Load_Balancing

Answer (score 0):

Simply use equal weighted routes. There is no need to do much more than that.

for example...

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer 0 0
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer 1 0
```

...this will balance traffic going out over the Dialer 1 and 2 interfaces.